# Transparent stage not allowing mouse clickthroughs

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to write a transparent stage in JavaFX. (This is working). However I don't want that mouse clicks go through. Funnily my code is working on Windows but not on Linux. My question is why I observe this difference  (despite javafx beeing designed as multiplatform library) and how I can fix the code so that it is working on both Linux and Windows.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.application.Platform;

public class Main extends Application {
    final Text text1 = new Text(10, 40, "Hello World!");
    text1.setFont(new Font(40));
    final Group g = new Group(text1);
    final Scene scene = new Scene(g);

    final Color c = new Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 / 250);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    scene.setFill(c);
    stage.setScene(scene); 
    stage.sizeToScene(); 
    stage.show(); 
}
```

Please note: If I set `final Color c = new Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 / 250);` to `final Color c = new Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);` clicks will also go through on windows. However I can live with this little intransparency as long as this intransparency doesn't get to obvious.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the `Node#setMouseTransparent(false)` to your Group for example ?

Comment: @Pagbo Yes unfortunatley this does not affect the behaviour. I also tried `scene.setFill(null);` instead of `scene.setFill(c);`, different Styles ...